# pip install mysql-python / mysqlclient returns index error

Tags: python, mysql, pip

i ran all sorts of myql connectors i can find but all of them, after i do:

`pip install mysqldb-python`

ends up with the following error:

```
Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz (82kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.3MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/6j/7lsh4_b55vz24ht7xv83syq0t4yg60/T/pip-build-KAOKCO/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range
```

all of the mysql dbs seem to have this issue...but not other packages via pip (like requests for example)

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: @Olia 2.7.13 i have tried with the python3 version as well using pip3...same issue